# Convert HTMLString to HTML using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ipad, uiwebview

I have a string which is basically an HTML String like this -

```
  var str =  "<section id='section1' class='class1'> <h3>Type 3 Heading</h3><p>Some text goes in <span> here</span> </p></section>"
```

I m trying to convert this HTMLString to real HTML Components using this below jQuery function and placing it in the div id **sampleSection** like this -

```
$('#sampleSection').html(str);
```

But it  is still loading as normal string, it does take html elements into consideration but places it as normal string like this -

```
Type 3 Heading Some text goes in here
```

I want it like this -

#### Type 3 Heading

Some text goes in here

Note - I am trying to load this on iPad InAppWebView with local HTML and script files. Is there something I m missing or do I need to do it differently? Thanks for your help.

```js
var str =  "<section id='section1' class='class1'> <h3>Type 3 Heading</h3><p>Some text goes in <span> here</span> </p></section>"
$("#sample").html(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sample"></div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; your `<h3>` tag is followed by `</h>`, which will be ignored.

Comment: I have corrected it now. It was a typo. Sorry.

Comment: it's work with close tag.

Comment: @nOObiOS have you tried the fixed typo in your actual code?

Comment: @Pointy - yes, I did

Comment: @nOObiOS OK click the code snippet above. It seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the closing tag of h3..
You have closed it as ...

```
var str =  "<section id='section1' class='class1'> <h3>Type 3 Heading</h3><p>Some text goes in <span> here</span> </p></section>"
```